# Fullcalendar columnheaderformat attribute

Tags: fullcalendar

I'm using fullcalendar (v3) and I can't configure properly the *columnheaderformat* attribute. Thanks in advance.

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
     locale: 'es',
     firstDay: 1,
     defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
     header: false,
     footer: false,
     allDaySlot : false,
     slotEventOverlap: false,
     columnHeaderFormat: 'ddd'
});
```

Comment: this was introduced in v3.8, as per https://fullcalendar.io/docs/columnHeaderFormat. So which exact version do you have? "v3" is not an accurate enough description. And what does "configure properly" mean? The setting you've shown above is valid. What's your expected result?

Answer (score 1):

I've checked my fullcalendar version and it's v3.5.1. I changed columnHeaderFormat with columnFormat and it works ok. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

for fullcalendar v5.8.0+

**dayHeaderFormat**

```
    initialView: 'timeGridWeek',
      views: {
         timeGridWeek: {
         dayHeaderFormat: { weekday: 'long' },
         }
      },
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

If you are using v4, place this code before the calendar.render():

```
moment.updateLocale('es', {
        monthsShort : [ "Ene", "Feb", "Mar", "Abr", "May", "Jun","Jul", "Ago", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dic" ],
        months: [ "Enero", "Febrero", "Marzo", "Abril", "Mayo", "Junio","Julio", "Agosto", "Septiembre", "Octubre", "Noviembre", "Diciembre" ],
        weekdays: [ "Domingo","Lunes", "Martes", "Miércoles", "Jueves", "Viernes", "Sábado"],
        weekdaysShort: [ "Dom","Lun", "Mar", "Mié", "Jue", "Vie", "Sáb"],
    });
```